# Databricks autoloader writing data with invalid characters in column name

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-autoloader

when trying to use databricks' autoloader for writing data, the nested columns contain invalid characters

```
Found invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=" in the column names of your schema.
```

How to deal with this issue?
Note again that it is the nested columns, not the outermost columns themselves. The latter would be easily fixed with a

```
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.select([col(c).alias(re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z\_]+","",c)) for c in df.columns])
```

How do I reach the nested columns, as they're not yet exploded?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing to Delta Lake you can use [column mapping](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-column-mapping.html#column-mapping-on-databricks) to get around this.